# Is it work performance profiler in visual studio 2015 community or any other solution for xamarin forms application

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am working on xamarin forms application in visual studio 2015 community. I want to check performance of our xamarin forms application. if i want to use xamarin profiler, I should have visual studio enterprises addition. How can i check the performance of our xamarin forms application. Please help me.

Comment: Use `Console.WrliteLine` graciously if you do not have a profiler.

Answer (score 0):

If you can not use the Xamarin Profiler you are still able to use native Profilers like Android Profiler and Xcode Instruments. In fact these are the better profilers because they are able to show you the real impact when it comes to memory consumption and/ or leaks.

Android Profiler comes with Android Studio. For Xcodes Instruments you need a Mac. A bonus is that for both tools plenty of how-to-guides are available.

Comment: Hello tequila slammer.                                                                                           Thank you for your reply. I want to check the xamarin forms applicaiton performance without xamarin profiler. Can i use performance profiler for xamarin forms in visual studio 2015 community.I am not working any native applications...

Comment: Of course you do. Xamarin, basically, is a wrapper around native apis. As such your app can be profiled with native tools.

The Xamarin profiler is not bound to a Visual Studio version. It is a an application that stands for his one.